# Locust, Realbrowserlocusts and running from config files .ymal

Tags: selenium, locust

I'm attempting to configure running realbrowserlocusts load tests using config files (.yml) for easier automation. I'm using locust version 0.13.5 with the latest versions of realbrowserlocusts and selenium.

When I run command to read the yml file I get an error:
locust --config=C:\PycharmProjects\locustproject\config\locust.yml

locust: error: unrecognized arguments: --config

I don't believe the version 0.13.5 supports running from config files but I know locust versions >1.x don't support realbrowserlocusts. The question is? What verion of locustio support realbrowserlocusts running tests using config files?

Are there plans to upgrade realbrowserslocusts to using the latest versions of locust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

realbrowserlocusts is abandoned, you may want to check out `locust-plugins`'s WebdriverUser (https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins#users)

For running master-slave, have a look at https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-swarm

(oh and to answer your question more specifically: config file support was added after 1.0, so no such compatible version exists)